# Gulp plugin to auto crop images (like Gimp does)?

Tags: image, image-processing, gulp, gimp

If you're not familiar auto crop in gimp crops the image of all surrounding white or transparent space.

I'm currently using gulp-gm and gulp-image-optimization. How can I achieve the same auto crop functionality of gimp also with gulp?

Answer (score 1):

Found it using gm("img.png").trim()

http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#trim